# Interaction between molecules of real gas

Tags: thermodynamics, gas

I read that the interaction of molecules in a real gas is attraction. Why is it specifically attraction ?? I mean there wouldn't be any repulsion between them and why is that? Thank u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is repulsion if the molecules become sufficiently close because the electronic orbitals aren't happy to overlap (see [Pauli repulsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_interaction)).

Further away though, the attraction is due to to the [van der Waals interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force).